# Async issue - not updating UI

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8

I am using async method in my Windows 8 development. but it is not updating the UI until it finishes executing full method.

here is my code.

below method calls when user presses refresh button on screen.

```
public async override void ExceuteRefresh()
    {
        IsBusy = true;             //This is bounded to my UI to show progress bar, but its not updating to UI
        foreach (var category in CategoryObservableColl)
                {
                    CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(category, true);
                }          
   }

private async void CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(Category category, bool isReFresh)
    {            
           var feed = await _dataService.GetOnlineRssFeedAsync(category.RssFeedLink.URL);
           var newsCategory = _dataService.GetCategoryFromFeed(feed, true, category.RssFeedLink);
            if (newsCategory != null)
           {
                 isRefreshCount +=1;
           }                                    
           if(isRefreshCount ==9)
       {
         IsBusy = false;
       }                                      

     }
```

IsBusy has implemented InotifyPropertyChanged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. tried following approach.

```
public override async void ExceuteRefresh()
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => IsBusy = true);
        _reloadCategories = false;
        _refreshLinkCount = 0;

        try
        {
            foreach (var category in CategoryObservableColl)
            {
                _refreshLinkCount += 1;
                await CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(category, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MainPage.ShowMessage("Something Went wrong!. " + ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Also made following method return type as task.
        private async Task CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(Category category, bool isReFresh)
{
}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Change `async void CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(...)` to `async Task CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(...)`
2. Change method call to `await CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(category, true);`
3. Change `public async override void ExceuteRefresh()` to `public async override Task ExceuteRefresh()`
4. Replace `IsBusy = false;` to below given code. You need to use UI thread to update the UI.

`await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => IsBusy = false);`

Comment: public override async void ExceuteRefresh()
        {
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => IsBusy = true);
 foreach (var category in CategoryObservableColl)
                {
                    _refreshLinkCount += 1;
                    await CheckforOnlineUpdatesAsync(category, true);
                }
}